# How to define an array in protobuf?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

my server need an array input, like

```
[
  {
    "name":"ada",
    "age":"20"
  }
]
```

and I have no idea to define the protobuf， thank you for your consideration

Answer (score 4):

Arrays aren't a concept in protobuf; there is `repeated`, but how that is interpreted is implementation specific; it *could* be an array, but it doesn't need to be; as for the .proto:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
message SomeWrapper {
    repeated SomeInner items = 1;
}
message SomeInner {
    string name = 1;
    int32 age = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have **ListProduct** api which is returning slice.

**Product struct**

```
type Product struct {
     ID int32
     Name String 
     Price int32
     Category string
}
```

**ListProduct Resp**

```
[]Product
```

**Answer** : product.proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";
package product;
option go_package = "product/grpc";
message Product {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2; 
    int32 price = 3;
    int32 category = 4;
    
}
message ListProductResponse{ repeated Product products = 1; }
```

If you want **map[int32]Product**

```
message ListProductResponse{ map< int32, Product> products = 1; }
```